# Residential ISP possibly blocking SSH and other odd high ports - how to verify?

Tags: ssh, firewall, port, isp

I have recently had a problem in a scenario where I am having to run SSH and some other high number port services behind a residential connection. I am suspecting that the ISP is performing some level of stateful packet watching to block various TCP and even perhaps UDP packets, however I'd like to verify my suspicions.  I'm just reaching a real impasse as it seems that all sorts of traffic on this interface on various ports are just being entirely dropped while other traffic seems to make it through just fine.  What would be the best way to determine whether my suspicions are true or if something else is at play?

Comment: This seems more appropriate for Superuser as it is related to home use.

Comment: Read their TOS and/or contact their support.

Comment: If they are, then you don't actually have Internet access. What you have is access to the world wide web and maybe some other services.